# How to check input when it change by a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't check my input when a function change the input value. I tried this:
`$(selectElement).on("change keyup paste click", ()=>{ //Do something })`
,This method only works when user insert something in the input but when a function change the value, it doesn't workout! Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have to trigger the change.

Comment: Setting a value doesn't trigger a change event, which is tied only to user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the button to fire the change event on the `<input type="text">` field by issuing a [`jQuery.fn.trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) call with an event is is designed to listen to.

```js
$('#input-txt').on('change keyup paste click', (e) => {
  console.log('Text changed!');
});

$('#click-btn').on('click', e => $('#input-txt').trigger('change'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-txt" type="text" value="Change me!" />
<button id="click-btn">Click me!</button>
```

Same thing using pure JavaScript (ES6).

```js
addEventListeners('#input-txt', 'change keyup paste click', e => {
  console.log('Text changed!');
});

addEventListener('#click-btn', 'click', e => {
  triggerEvent('#input-txt', 'change');
});

function addEventListener(el, eventName, fn) {
  el = typeof el === 'string' ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
  el.addEventListener(eventName, fn);
}
function addEventListeners(el, events, fn) {
  el = typeof el === 'string' ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
  events.trim().split(/\s+/).forEach(eventName => addEventListener(el, eventName, fn));
}
function triggerEvent(el, eventName) {
  el = typeof el === 'string' ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<input id="input-txt" type="text" value="Change me!" />
<button id="click-btn">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: I didn't workout. You can check it: document.getElementById("input-txt").value= "Test"

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery code catches immediate changes to any element, and should work across all browsers:

```
 $('.selectElements').each(function() {
   var elem = $(this);

   // Save current value of element
   elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

   // Look for changes in the value
   elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
      // If value has changed...
      if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
       // Updated stored value
       elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());

       // Do action
       console.log('change!');
     }
   });
 });
```